# Is it good practice to override the destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, destructor

Is it good practice to `override` destructors? Why or why not?
Example:

```
class Foo : Base
{
public:
    ~Foo() override {}
};
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the duplicate question doesn't answer if it is good practice, in fact there is an unanswered comment about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() {}
};
struct Foo : Base {
  ~Foo() override {}
};
```

this compiles.

```
struct Base {
  ~Base() {}
};
struct Foo : Base {
  ~Foo() override {}
};
```

this does not.

```
struct Base {
  ~Base() {}
};
struct Foo : Base {
  virtual ~Foo() {}
};
```

This compiles.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cd4fb7703e65b38).

If your goal is to state in `Foo` that you expect `Base` to have a `virtual` destructor, the simplest way to do it is with the `override` keyword on `~Foo`.  As the semantics of deleting a `Foo*` through a `Base*` change significantly depending on if `~Foo` is `virtual`, this may be useful to some people.

Others may be offended by using the term `override` to refer to this situation.

Determine if people being offenced by using `override` is more, or less important than being able to state in `Foo` that `Base` has a virtual destructor, so deleting an instance of `Foo` via a pointer to `Base` is defined behavior.  I cannot make that decision for you.

As @HowardHinnant has stated in the comments, there are consequences to adding an explicit destructor; if you do so, follow the rule of 5 and either `=default`, `=delete` or implement the copy/move object construct/assignment operators.

It may be easier to `static_assert` that `Base` has a virtual destructor, unless you need the destructor for some other reason.

Comment: Agreed (and upvoted).  But also consider whether or not using an implicitly declared destructor is best.  When you add a destructor (`override` or not), you implicitly disable implicitly declared move members.  And if your copy members are implicit, you are relying on deprecated behavior.  This should all be taken into account as you add a user-declared destructor.  Adding a destructor _only_ for the purpose of marking it `override` may be overkill.  There are other ways to ensure `~Foo()` is `virtual`, e.g.: `static_assert(std::has_virtual_destructor<Foo>{})`.